# Forcefully un-suspend a Parallels VM without starting Parallels

Tags: virtualization, vmware, parallels-desktop

I recently updated to Mac OS X 10.12.5, which is a beta version as of right now, and Parallels Desktop has subsequently refused to start. It sits for a little bit with a spinner and then quietly dies. The log entries shown in `Console.app` for "parallels" are not helpful, so I decided to try using VMware Fusion instead. Unfortunately, the virtual machine that I want to import to VMware is suspended and VMware refuses to accept suspended VMs. So, I tried deleting the `.mem` file for the VM, but VMware still refused to open it. I deleted the `suspended.png` image for the VM and VMware got a little farther with it, allowing me to select my target location for the import, but it still just ended up saying "This virtual machine can not be imported in Hybrid Shutdown state." I'm at a loss for how to import my VM to VMware since I can't shut it down via Parallels, since it won't open. Anyone know how to forcefully un-suspend a Parallels VM without starting Parallels?

Answer (score 1):

Check that you have option ShutdownReason"**0**" in config.pvs.
I think you have "**2**". It works for me.

Comment: Hmm, interesting advice. I have not had this issue for a long while after updating Parallels, but I'll have to revisit your answer should it come up again.